# sort string date and sort it

Tags: java, sorting, compare

I would like to use sort my list of article by date (`dd/mm/yyyy`). 
Dates are String.

```
public class ArticleComparator implements Comparator<Article> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Article a1, Article a2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = a1.getDate().compareTo(a2.getDate());
        if(result == 0) 
            result = a1.getAuteur().getPseudo().compareTo(a2.getAuteur().getPseudo());
    return result;
}
```

```
public class ReseauSocial {

    private HashMap<String, CompteUtilisateur> utilisateurs; 
    private List <Article> article; 

    public ReseauSocial() {
    }

    public void tirerArticles() {
        Collections.sort(article, new ArticleComparator());
    }

    public void connecter(String pseudo, String mdp) {
    }
}
```

But can you help me to sort dates from newest to oldest

---

Thank you for your answer but it does not works.. That is I obtain after modifying my code

```
public class MainClass {

    static List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Article a1 = new Article ("article1", "TP1", true, "01/02/2018");
        Article a2 = new Article ("article2", "TP2", true, "01/02/2019");
        articles.add(a1);
        articles.add(a2);

        ReseauSocial rsc = new ReseauSocial(articles);
        rsc.tirerArticles();

        for(int i = 0; i<articles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("Articles : "+ articles.get(i).getDate().toString()+"\n");

        }

    }

}
```

```
Article 1 : Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2019
Articles 2 : Thu Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2018
Articles : 01/02/2018
Articles : 01/02/2019
```

Comment: *Dates are String* — why? You could use some comparable class for that, let's say `java.time.LocalDate`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an already comparable data type (a `class` that `implements Comparable`),
then you can just return the result of its own `compareTo` method:

```
public int compare(Article a1, Article a2) {
    // define a suitable formatter
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    // parse both dates
    LocalDate ldOne = LocalDate.parse(a1.getDate(), dtf);
    LocalDate ldTwo = LocalDate.parse(a2.getDate(), dtf);
    // compare the dates and return the result
    return ldOne.compareTo(ldTwo);
}
```

> Please note that using `String`s for dates is generally not a good practice. Consider refactoring your class attributes that represent dates to have a suitable data type.

Comment: When I compile, I have this error ... `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/02/2019' could not be parsed at index 0`

Comment: Hmm... In my IDE it does what it is supposed to... Could you show the class `Article` and where the time comes from in *`Article 1 : Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2019`*? If you have time information in that "date"-`String`, then another data type should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse date first

```
public int compare(Article a1, Article a2) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   Date date1 = sdf.parse(a1.getDate());
   Date date2 = sdf.parse(a2.getDate());

   int result = date1.compareTo(date2);
   if(result == 0) { 
      result = a1.getAuteur().getPseudo().compareTo(a2.getAuteur().getPseudo());
   }

   return result;
}
```